# PHPUnit mock parent method

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have problem with mocking parent method, this is example:

```
class PathProvider
{
    public function getPath()
    {
        return isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '/';
    }
}


class Uri extends PathProvider
{
    public function getParam($param)
    {
        $path = $this->getPath();

        if ($path == $param)
            return 'OK';
        else
            return 'Bad';
    }
}
```

And now i want mock method getPath(), and call method getParam() which recive mocked value.

```
$mock = $this->getMock('PathProvider');

$mock->expects($this->any())
->method('getPath')
->will($this->returnValue('/panel2.0/user/index/id/5'));
```

I was write this part, but I don't know how I must pass this mocked value to testing method.

Comment: I think a redesign might be in order, a Uri is not a PathProvider, it just needs its services.

Comment: @GordonM has totally right! You should make PathProvider as a dependency and inject it inside Uri class (through controller or settter). Don't overuse intheritance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need mock `Uri` class. You can mock only one method (`getPath`), like that:

```
$sut = $this->getMock('Appropriate\Namespace\Uri', array('getPath'));

$sut->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getPath')
    ->will($this->returnValue('/panel2.0/user/index/id/5'));
```

And then you can test your object as usual:

```
$this->assertEquals($expectedParam, $sut->getParam('someParam'));
```

Comment: When I calling method like you tell I recive error: `Call to undefined method Mock_Uri_b1cf6492::getParam()`

Comment: probably you forgot add appropriate namespace to getMock method. Look at my example above (I'll edit answer)

Comment: In my app, I have correct namespace, but I always have error as above.

Comment: My mistake, sorry - everything is OK. I have set wrong bootloader to launch tests.

Answer (score 4):

Me and my friends write mockito like mocking library. [ouzo-goddies#mocking](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/tests.html#mocking)

```
$mock = Mock::create('\Appropriate\Namespace\Uri');
Mock::when($mock)->getPath()->thenReturn(result);
```